# Any way a GSM sim 900 can still work (USA)?

Tags: gsm, gps, tinygps

so I’m pretty new to arduino and have been working for weeks on a GPS tracker using a sim 900 and a knock off neo 6M. All my code seemed to be working but for some reason I could not get the sim900 to establish a connection. Took me long enough to find out 2G carriers have been pretty much shut down. This is for a project and I don’t have time to start over with a 4G shield. Are there any cell carriers that still support 2G? What are my options? I don’t know what to do

Edit: more detail, I’m using the sim 900 to send an sms with a gps location

Comment: we don't either ... you did not say what you are doing, so it is impossible to guess any alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I got a connection! I live in PA but when I went to Boston for school I got 2G service. Maybe carriers haven’t fully shut it down.